# [hector_height_mapping-3] process has died [pid 8937,

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, rplidar, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I download a package `rplidar_ros` and `launch rpliar_ros veiw_slam.launch`. And then ,sometiems it could play, but sometimes it will be died. Tomorrow, it has worked well , but tonight it show error:

```
[hector_height_mapping-3] process has died [pid 8937, exit code -11, cmd /home/robot2/catkin_rp/devel/lib/hector_mapping/hector_mapping
__name:=hector_height_mapping __log:=/home/robot2/.ros/log/86f925ea-bf55-11e5-b64a-000c29d3d3bc/hector_height_mapping-3.log]. log file: /home/robot2/.ros/log/86f925ea-bf55-11e5-b64a-000c29d3d3bc/hector_height_mapping-3*.log
```

when I restart it, for a moment it broken and show:

```
[hector_height_mapping-3] process has died [pid 9191, exit code -11, cmd  /home/robot2/catkin_rp/devel/lib/hector_mapping/hector_mapping
__name:=hector_height_mapping __log:=/home/robot2/.ros/log/86f925ea-bf55-11e5-b64a-000c29d3d3bc/hector_height_mapping-3.log]. log file: /home/robot2/.ros/log/86f925ea-bf55-11e5-b64a-000c29d3d3bc/hector_heigh
```

This makes me quesion for it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224592/%5Bhector_height_mapping-3%5D-process-has-died-%5Bpid-8937,/) by [RB复燃](https://answers.ros.org/users/25374/rb%E5%A4%8D%E7%87%83/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The height mapping node certainly isn't supposed to crash, but it is meant for a specialized application and you probably shouldn't be using it :) In any case, a backtrace would be required to get a better idea of what is going on.

What you really want is probably starting a standard mapping setup however, which should not crash in the first place.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0